# Custom extensions throwing 404 after installing patch for magento

Tags: magento, patch

I have installed the following security patches in my magento site: 4291,6237,7616,5344,5994,6285,6482,6788,7405.

Before that all of the custom modules worked fine, but now they aren't. Here is my `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Moduleadmin>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <depends>Custom_Module</depends>
        </Custom_Moduleadmin>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custommoduleadmin>
                    <file>custommoduleadmin.xml</file>
                </custommoduleadmin>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml> 
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <custommoduleadmin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Custom_Moduleadmin</module>
                <frontName>custommoduleadmin</frontName>
            </args>
        </custommoduleadmin>
    </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
          <Custom_Moduleadmin_Adminhtml_custommoduleadminController>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/custommodule/adminhtml_custommodule/#]]></from>
            <to>/custommoduleadmin/adminhtml_custommoduleadmin/</to>
          </Custom_Moduleadmin_Adminhtml_custommoduleadminController>
        </rewrite>

    </global>
</config>
```

I toke help from [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68411/patch-5994-is-causing-module-adminhtml-404-status-error) link.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow I found a solution to this by changing this:

```
<routers>
    <custommoduleadmin>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Custom_Moduleadmin</module>
            <frontName>custommoduleadmin</frontName>
        </args>
    </custommoduleadmin>
</routers>
```

To:

```
<routers>
    <adminhtml>
        <args>
            <modules after="Mage_Adminhtml">Custom_Moduleadmin</modules>
            <frontName>custommoduleadmin</frontName>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
</routers>
```

this.